# Check for new comments in Triage review queue automatically

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage, live-refresh

Often I see (and sometimes am responsible for) redundant semi-scripted review comments posted on the same question within minutes of each other. Generally, this is because the Triage review queue makes no attempt to keep track of comments as they're posted, so the only way to tell that there have been any is to (as is so often the case in queues) open the question in another tab in order to check.

So, can we get the comment notifications that the rest of the site has?

Comment: If the same auto-comment has already been used then another one won't be posted, or are you talking about custom comments?

Comment: @worldofjr: That's only the case for LQP queue auto-comments. I'm referring to Triage, which doesn't have those. All comments in Triage are custom. (Some are populated with userscripts or copypasting from text files, of course.)

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake.