# Disable duplicate flagging in Triage

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, triage, disputed-flags

I have a rather daring proposal that may **increase** duplicate closure rates: *disable both Duplicate entries in Triage* <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> *dialog*.

What could possibly motivate such a counter-intuitive idea? Well, [earlier I asked if this flagging was doing any good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290533/is-flagging-dupes-in-triage-mostly-useless-completely-useless-or-worse-than-us). It's not all that great. And whenever the outcome is anything but Unsalvageable, the flag is [automatically and immediately disputed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289386/are-raised-flags-during-triage-disputed-if-others-disagree), so it doesn't do any good.

If, instead, we could get reviewers to open the post and flag it from there, the result should be substantially better: higher accuracy, up with site norms or better, and nearly the same best-case speed as Triage can presently manage, with far less disputed flags. And because of the reduction in disputes, *average* closure time and closure *volume* should both improve significantly.

Alternatively, just disable the Triage auto-disputation code for Duplicate flags only. It's not like disputing those is ever particularly helpful; it's very easy to consider a question that's actually a dupe to Look OK, especially for reviewers with only 500-some rep.

Comment: I rather like this idea since I'm not really in the mindset of hunting for duplicates in triage.  Especially since I can't filter by tags I might actually know where duplicates are located.

Comment: Hmm, I got a close vote for "unclear" ... if someone could point out what, precisely, is unclear about this proposal I would much appreciate that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although Triage is clearly *not* designed for identifying duplicates, I've been surprised at just how useful it is for this purpose in those instances where you're able to quickly identify a question that has been asked before. And [as Siguza noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300723/disable-duplicate-flagging-in-triage/300767#300767), there are no issues for close *votes* raised in Triage - they will cause the question to enter close review regardless of what else happens. For these reasons, I'd be reluctant to remove the option entirely.

The simple solution here is simply to stop disputing most close flags in Triage, duplicate *or otherwise*. Since the bulk of the problems here arise from Should Be Improved reviews, [close flags will no longer be disputed when that is the consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289658/lots-of-disputed-flags-since-yesterday/300787#300787).

There's still a small chance that these flags may be erroneously disputed by reviewers who choose Looks OK when reviewing, but this should effect relatively few cases.

Comment: I'd like to see the numbers on that last possibility and I'll have to adjust my workflow so if I suspect a post might be dupe I hit SBI instead, but OK.

Comment: Probably makes sense to check the comments for "possible duplicate of..." before deciding in any case. As for numbers... This affects *at worst* 8% of duplicate flags raised on questions after they enter triage; few enough that we could probably have a bigger effect on the outcome by improving audits than by special-casing duplicates here (there's a bigger opportunity cost to sending stuff into close review that doesn't need to be closed).

Comment: Oh, I do, but Triage doesn't load new comments after I load the review, so if it wasn't already there, it's not going to be considered.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: That sounds like you should report it as a bug, or at least as a feature request, then. (In fact, I'm pretty sure I know how to fix this; I might add it to SOUP at some point.) Of course, it's only useful if you happen to have the question open for review at exactly the same time as when someone else flags it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: [I did](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283827/check-for-new-comments-in-triage-review-queue-automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Your request doesn't take users with >3K reputation into account, who don't raise duplicate flags anymore, but instead cast close votes.
I wasn't able to find any information on whether close votes are also somehow discarded if the outcome is not "Unsalvagable", but I doubt it, because close votes (or votes in general) usually don't get "disputed".
So your request would effectively make it **more bothersome** for >3K rep users to mark something as a duplicate in the Triage queue.

But even if close votes somehow do get discarded, I still vote against the removal of the duplicate entries, simply because if the outcome is not "Unsalvagable", then **the majority of reviewers disagreed with you**.

The real problem of the Triage queue is that [people don't know what "Should Be Improved" means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294318/please-rename-the-should-be-improved-button).

I **do** support your alternative of disabling auto-disputation for Triage-based duplicate flags, for the simple reason that searching for a duplicate takes a lot more time and effort than simply clicking "Looks OK" or "Should Be Improved", and is therefore much less likely to be faulty.

Comment: All right. In the specific case of duplicates, it is entirely misleading to say that the majority of reviewers disagreed. Rather, they were almost certainly *not even aware* that "duplicate of X" was on the table: Triage does not load new comments after a review item loads, and anyone who reviewed before you will not of course see your auto-comment, and there is no other way to tell that Duplicate has been selected besides going through to select it yourself.

Comment: Close voters are an interesting case, I'll admit, but I'm not entirely convinced marking as Duplicate *in Triage* is really how the queue works well anyway, even leaving out the problems with flagging. It just doesn't fit the intended speedy workflow, since only really silver or gold badgers can be expected to have the mental command of possible dupes to be able to scan most questions and figure out what they duplicate. (Only e.g. Java NPE style questions are really practical to dupe in Triage.)