# Disputed flag on seemingly obvious duplicate (Am I doing it wrong?)

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

I'm pretty new to the review queues, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753054/bash-how-to-remove-leading-whitespace-from-a-string) seemed to be a pretty obvious duplicate; I literally googled the exact title of the question and found the answer in the first result, so I flagged it and left a comment detailing exactly what part of the answer would be of interest to the asker.

Three other reviewers disagreed with me, however, and my flag was marked as disputed.

My question is, did I do the right thing here?  Did I miss something that should've prevented me marking this as a dupe?

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300787/5240004

Comment: The user agreed that it was more or less a dupe... whitespace is whitespace... Your flag is correct

Comment: @theB Hmm... that's interesting. The behavior described in that answer seems undesirable in the case of duplicate flags. It doesn't really seem like someone marking "Looks OK" in the triage queue should dispute a dupe flag.

Comment: I understand the confusion The question itself is not a duplicate (left trim versus all trim), an answer from one applies to both (you could say 'the solution is duplicate'). This must happen frequently. [I'm trying to find a meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+same+answer) that describes what to do in these cases.

Comment: [Here is one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57836/proper-handling-for-different-question-same-answer), thought not exactly about *similar* questions. [Related 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107617/similar-question-same-answer-an-other-user-gave-to-the-other-question) and [Related 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). The accepted answer there is relevant.

Comment: You were correct; the question is now closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: If it ends up in the triage queue, all manner of strange things will happen to it, as most of the reviewers there probably don't have the technical knowledge needed to review it. There will always be people who try to review though, even though they don't know a thing about the topic.

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300723/disable-duplicate-flagging-in-triage