# Must an answer literally be a copy & paste job to count as a "duplicate"?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

I thought **NO**. Just today I flagged a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34220172/5297359) as duplicate. The OP said, this does not solve his problem, because of a reason I can not comprehend.

I went to my flag history and saw that this flag is *disputed*.

The relevant part of the answer, which I thought it was a duplicate from is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
```

The accepted answer from the OP is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
```

My opinion: With 2 seconds thinking, the first solution just needs the domain name to work, so it's a duplicate.

To clarify: I have no problem with the *disputed* itself, but how close has an answer to be, to flag it as a duplicate. Is it really OK, that the Op's doesn't even have to think about it and give them a copy paste solution?

By the way, If this question is inappropriate, just downvote and I'll delete it.

Comment: You want to know whether *An answer must be a copy-paste duplicate __for it to be flagged as duplicate__?!* Without the last part your question is somewhat incomprehensible.

Comment: @deceze, Yes you almost got me right. I just wanted to know how close has a question to be and if it was wrong to flag this as an duplicate. I guess my english is not good enough that is comprehensible to all, sorry for that. The answer from *rene* helped a lot, and so are yours. I keep flagging like I did before.

Comment: The OP said, this does not solve his problem, because of a reason I can not comprehend', that's easy - the OP has zero software development skills.  S/he is likely a student who needs to hand in its assignment without making any effort, or someone doing others' homework for cash and wants the work completely finished by SO slaves without all that tawdry editing afterwards.

Comment: @MartinJames you are a little bit pre-occupied with the SO-slavery theme lately, aren't you?

Comment: [htaccess] and [regex] questions notoriously fall in the *don't make me think* bucket.  They do get serviced anyway, several SO users almost exclusively answer such questions, earn a lot of rep on them and never seem to tire at answering the same question over and over again.  The profile of [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) is notable, bragging about earning a gold badge in all major language [tags] by just answering regex questions :)  Best thing to do is just add them to your ignored tags so you never have to look at or get annoyed by them.

Comment: @rene - my level of pissed-offness is somewhat extreme ATM, yes:(

Comment: @HansPassant, Impresive example. Maybe I should stop flagging and start to answer just regex questions, wooohooo. No that's a joke. But I think i got the (missing) link, that duplicate and regex doesn't fit very well to most of the "Triage" reviews

Comment: Well, the only gold language badge [that user has earned so far is \[python\]](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj?tab=badges&sort=class), @HansPassant.

Comment: To be fair, there's a significant difference between the two answers on a server with name-based virtual servers. You need to understand that the wildcard needs to be replaced with a specific domain if you only want to rewrite that domain.

Comment: use the [`SO Close Vote Review`](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room when this happens. Unfortunately I can't get to chat from work to help with that chat room because of the damn proxy filters! :-(

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The purpose of Stack Overflow is not to be a repository and creation engine for copy-pastable code snippets. We provide *answers to questions* with the implicit purpose of education; not mechanical turk code generators. So, no, a question doesn't need to be a 100% identical clone to be considered a duplicate. If that was the case, there'd be no duplicates at all, since every single problem is somewhat unique. As long as an existing answer provides the solution to the general problem and can easily be adapted to the OP's specific situation, it is a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I agree, have an upboat, but you should understand that the need for trivial editing can eat into the profits of those who take cash to do homework and then order SO slaves to do the actual work.  Many such slave drivers don't have the skill to do the editing anyway, can end up losing customers/clients and so have no way of paying club cover charges, buying beer or fueling up their BMWs/Audis.

Comment: I have complete understanding for this. ... *tumbleweed* ... :)

Comment: I agree 100% with the sentiment of your answer; that said, the charter promotes crap since they took the word *quality* out of it. They just want *quantity* any concern about *quality* is unwarranted now.

Answer (score 12):

Your flag got disputed because enough reviewers choose [Looks OK](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10523480) in the Triage queue.

I can't judge if your assessment of the applicability of the found duplicate is correct but I expect the reviewers to err on the safe side when they saw the OP challenge your call with, at first look, reasonable arguments. Reviewers don't tend to spend ages on reviews, specially not in looking for dupes, so that only left them with one of the other options. Given all the low quality stuff they are normally presented with, I can see why the majority choose *Looks OK*.

Keep flagging as you did, gain a little bit more rep to get you above 3K so can close vote. The reviewers in that queue tend to be a little bit more careful.

Comment: While I think deceze's answer is correct to the question, I think your answer is very important for me. So I just keep flagging like I did. This helped me a lot

Comment: Does the review system do _anything_ well?

Comment: @CodeCaster the review system is near-perfect, our expectance of the users using it is sometimes too high...

Comment: Well, if a duplicate-flag was disputed from triage, I think that's a bug in the system.

Comment: @Deduplicator what should have been the outcome then?

Comment: Simple: A dupe-flag cannot be resolved properly in triage, only in the CVQ or by closing.

Comment: @Deduplicator hmm, OK. So your take on it is to leave duplicate flags only be dismissed/declined when the close vote review item is completed?

Comment: @rene: Yes, as triage isn't geared for dupes at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator do you search for a FR/BUG on meta for this and if none found write a meta-post?

Comment: Not today, at least. As I have to go quite soon. I won't bemoan the missed opportunity if it's already done when I get around to it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: [Relevant feature-request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300723/), partially-completed. (Flags raised are no longer disputed by Requires Editing.)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends.

I can see why you would consider this answer to be a duplicate of the other one. And, indeed, in many other cases, I would agree with you.

However, the nature of this particular question leaves very little room for variety in the answers, decreasing the likelihood that you were "ripped off" by another author. And the fact of the matter is that your answer was wrong, while the newer answer was right. That is hardly "duplication".

I think that's enough to distinguish them in this specific case.