# Duplicate flag disputed despite the OP accepting older question's solution

Tags: bug, flags, duplicate-questions, disputed-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306121/while-clicking-a-button-go-to-next-view-controller-after-some-secondsios) as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920675/how-can-i-delay-a-method-call-for-1-second). Before doing so, I copied & pasted the same solution as a comment and as expected, it solved the OP's problem. Thus proving that it was indeed a duplicate question. He just wanted to call a method after a delay of specified time, which was what the older question was about as well.

But today I saw that it was resolved as [disputed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/4029561?group=1&status=4) (It was pending before today, as far as I can remember). Why wasn't it marked as helpful? Did I flag it wrongly?

Should we not flag a question as such which might use different words but requires the same solution? [This SE Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) says:

> *Basically, questions are duplicates if they have the same answers.*
>   *This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same*
>   *idea expressed in different words.*

It did have the same answer (but obviously required technical knowledge of the subject to know so).

But it also says:

> *Questions asking about the same aspect of the same concept, but with*
>   *different examples, may or may not be considered duplicates.*

They did use different examples and different scenarios despite having the same solution. So I am sort of confused here.

Comment: This was supposedly fixed http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300723/disable-duplicate-flagging-in-triage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It most definitely is a duplicate. To someone not familiar with iOS it may not seem that way though. One question asks about delaying a view controller's transition and the other is asking about delaying a method. Both questions do indeed have the same solution as you've stated. In the future I wouldn't post the answer as a comment on the duplicate question. If the answer was never provided in the comment the OP may have been more inclined to accept the duplicate suggestion.

Comment: He was a new guy so I thought it would be helpful to him if I gave him the answer before following the due procedure. It can be hard for a newbie to search for the right thing, speaking from experience. Besides, New users seldom do delete such questions as many of the 1 rep users just create accounts for one-time use. It was up to the reviewers in the end to remove it.